# Maximum Ajax Response Size of jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, post, webbrowser-control

I wrote a JQuerym code to make a POST ajax call from Android mobile device to a PhP code running on the same device (mobile becomes a web server). The code multiplies two matrices and returns the results as one matrix using json_encode($arrayname). It works fine while response is less than about 20k, but it is broken when exceed 20k size. I initiate the code from Google Chrome browser on my desktop (the code in mobile device is called like `http://192.168.1.1:8080/code.php` where IP is the address of the mobile device) and I can see the results in Google chrome browser (this is to better see the results). I googled alot and found some similar questions here, but they are talking about web.conf and some other staff which is incomplete to me (I am novice in web development and my question further is bound by mobile device).

Here is the POST call:

```
function callJSON(){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: URL_Multiply,
crossDomain: true,
data: {matrix1:input1[x],matrix2:input2[y],filename:z},
dataType: 'text',
success: function(res1, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
error: function (res1, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('POST failed.');}
    });//AJAX
}//CALLjson
```

Is there any way to overcome this limit? if not can I send the results as a file? I need to have real traffic towards the mobile device. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What webserver are you running PHP on?

Comment: I try PAW Server and KSWEB both.